# Any tool for WebDAV load testing?

Tags: webdav, load-testing

I want to generate WebDAV traffic *(to reproduce a bug in [an open source server](http://www.alfresco.com))*.

I know WebDAV is a layer over HTTP so I could generate such traffic by reading the protocol specification and sending tens of hand-crafted HTTP requests, but I don't want to re-invent the wheel, I guess someone has already written such a tool?

Ideally the tool would:

- Log in at a URL
- Randomly navigate directories
- Download/upload files from time to time.

Bonus if it is free/open source.

[This discussion](http://jmeter.512774.n5.nabble.com/Jmeter-and-Webdav-td3238663.html) suggests JMeter does not have this feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a tool called "Prestan" on [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/prestan/).  It's based on [this](http://www.webdav.org/papers/MSProject_TengXu.pdf) paper by Teng Xu

Answer (score 1):

There was no such tool, so I wrote one.

[Mecadaver](https://github.com/nicolas-raoul/Mecadaver) logs in at a WebDAV URL, and starts navigating directories at random, sometimes downloading documents, sometimes going back to the root.

- Runs as as many users as you want (you provide a list of usernames/passwords in a CSV file)
- Various parameters to make the load more intensive or less intensive.
- Open source

Note: [Silk Performer](http://www.borland.com/products/silkperformer/) can do WebDAV test loads as well, but it is very expensive.